# A dynamic html form placeholder

Tags: php, html, mysql, placeholder

I have made a Mysql table that holds information of users of the website. I am trying to make the information-uppdate-page. I want the form to hold the current values from the Mysql data in the placeholders of the textboxes. How can i do that using php,html and Mysqli? i tried the code:

```
placeholder = "<? php $_SESSION["tableVariable"] ?>]"
```

but that gave me garbage in the textbox.

Comment: Please provide additional information, bigger portion of you html. the php code where you retrieve the data from database. And why are you storing your data in session variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like stated, echo the variable (mind the quotes).

```
"<?php echo $_SESSION['tableVariable']; ?>"
```

However consider echoing the variable as the value of the form-item and not as a placeholder. This will prevent problems with validation, and validation should always be done when dealing with user-input.

```
<input type="text" name="inputName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['tableVariable']; ?>" placeholder="placeholder" required>
```

Comment: Thank you! Using the value attribute was what i was looking for

Answer (score -1):

```
placeholder = "<? php echo $_SESSION["tableVariable"] ?>]"
```

You need to echo the variable.

Answer (score -2):

Try this: `placeholder = "<? php echo $_SESSION['tableVariable'] ?>"`

Comment: “This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.”